# Render ValidationError in template

Tags: python, django

I am making a page for adding products to the web shop by the user, and I am having troubles with displaying `ValidationError` in my template. The `ValidationError` is raised if selected category isn't the most specific category to select. To select a category, the user has to go trough chained dependent combobox selection, where you start with one combobox for main category and once you select main category, another `<select>` appears for selecting a subcategory, and so on until the innermost subcategory is selected. Based on selected category, a different ModelForm is displayed. `category` is a field on my base Product model (from which other models, such as Book or Shoes, inherit) and isn't listed in ModelForms' inner Meta class fields, thus I can't have `clean_category` method on my ModelForms.

Here is my view:

```
@login_required
def product_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        main_category = request.session.get('main_category')
        create_product_form = mappings[main_category](request.POST)
        if create_product_form.is_valid():
            obj = create_product_form.save(commit=False)
            category = request.session.get('category')
            if Category.objects.get(id=category).is_leaf_node():
                obj.category = Category.objects.get(id=category)
                obj.save()
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Please select most specific category.')
    return render(request, 'products/product_create.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    })
```

How to render the ValidationError in the template, i.e. how can I have my `ValidationError` in my `{{ field.errors }}`? Currently I am seeing a stack trace.

Comment: You can use Django Form to validate the data and raise a message inside clean method of that form, then return that form to the template context so that you can see the error messages like this: `form.errors`